# Ecologically-balanced garden: dealing with pest infestations among challenging plants

Tags: pest-control

My garden has been maintained using the organic approach ever since I began caring for it in 2001.  I maintain recycling garden waste (dry leaves and branches) through composting and adding Humus , and supplement fruit trees with 7-3-7 fertilizer and organic foliage feed.

The bulk part of it consists of fruit trees. With time, few cacti and other succulents were being raised, with the larger ones being in the garden soil, and the smaller ones potted and placed on shelves along the garden wall. Gaps among the trees were recently filled with tropical plants, predominantly with large leaves as well as variegated ones. The gap fillers remained in their pots to reduce water consumption and prevent the trees from invading their root zones for water. Tropical plants are predominantly aroids, followed by Hoyas (hanging under the pergola) and few Begonias.

The succulents consist of cacti, aloes, agaves, Haworthias and Gasterias. You may have seen one of my previous posts, regarding a scale infestation among my Haworthias. The infestation resisted all chemical and non-chemical treatments. Any action ended up spreading the surviving scales to a level much worse than before. By trial and error, I noticed that Haworthias planted in small pots and kept rootbound and under more direct sun have done well and did not need much care and watering beyond what the other succulents needed. Most would grow pest free. Recently some scales appeared on few Haworthia specimens. They appear relatively healthy but occasional scales were holding on. After several applications of neem oil, an isolated few appeared to suffer from a more extensive infestation, so I stopped the treatment and discarded the infected ones. This is the same scenario, where applying any treatment actually made things worse.

The scales were different as well. I noticed they are much smaller and yellow. I looked through a magnifying glass. These are scales, and maybe of a different species. **The scales were too small for taking any clear photo**. They appear only on my Haworthias. All other plants are fine. Similarly, Yellow aphids appear on the pedicles of the Hoya flowers. I waterblast them even though the plants are not suffering. Here too, the aphids appear just on these plants and only on the flower stems few new shoots, but nowhere else. Some Hoya plants are not affected and the aphids appear to favor others. If my garden is ecologically balanced, then pests must meet their predators eventually, yet they thrive on some plants and not elsewhere.

Location and climate - Tel-Aviv, near the coast. Ladybug population is declining in recent years. climate is warm Mediterranean, Csa. What other predator insects should I introduce to keep the pest infestation in check?